# Something related to Polignac conjecture

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I would like that all of you interested in number theory and specially, in prime numbers, to take a look at this quite elementary approach on the problem related to the conjecture of Polignac, which says that for every $k \in \mathbb N$ there exist infinitely many consecutive prime numbers with the difference $2k$ (case $k=1$ is the twin primes conjecture).

Let us suppose that for every $k \in \mathbb N$ the set $S_k=\{n\in\mathbb N|\;(p_{n+1}-p_n=2k)\}$ is finite (which could also be the case). This means that for every $k\in\mathbb N$ there exist $a(k)\in\mathbb N$ such that $p_{a(k)+m+1}-p_{a(k)+m}>2k$, for every $m\in\mathbb N$. But this implies that $\ lim_{n\to\infty} (p_{n+1}-p_n)=\infty$.

So this observation says that if $lim_{n\to\infty}(p_{n+1}-p_n)\neq\infty$ then there exist at least one $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $S_k$ is infinite, and there is connection with conjecture of Polignac.

It could be the case that somewhere in this short proof I made the mistake so I welcome comments about the proof itself, do you see any error?

And can we show somehow that $lim_{n\to\infty}(p_{n+1}-p_n)\neq\infty$?

Comment: Could you please explain how you deduced your inequality from the assumption that $S_k$ is finite for any positive integer? Thanks.

Comment: So far as I know, no one has been able to disprove $\lim_{n\to\infty}(p_{n+1}-p_n)=\infty$.

Comment: @awllower : 

If $S_k$ is finite then all the natural numbers greater then the maximal $n\in\ S_k$, in other words all such $m>n$ must imply $p_{m+1}-p_m>2k$, it is obvious to me.

Comment: Gerry, what about the proof, do you agree with all the steps?

Comment: What if $p_{m+1}-p_m<2k$?

Comment: It cannot be the case because $m$ is greater than the maximal $n\in\ S_k$, the difference $2k$ is by the assumption possible only finite number of times, that is the assumption.

Comment: But the difference is $<2k$, not equal to it, hence not contradicting our hypothesis. So it might occur? Or should you impose that $m$ is actually greater than the maxima of every $S_i$ for $i=1,...,k$? Notice that, if 0 is allowed to belong to $\mathbb N$ then the assumption is obviously wrong.

Comment: You are speaking here about $a(k)$, not about $m$, but such $a(k)$ must exist for every $k$ because there is only finitely many $n\in\ S_i$ for $i=1,2,...k$. I do not see why your statement contradicts my conclusions, maybe you can construct a counterexample?

Comment: I did not claim to contradict your statement here. In any case, I know the reason your statements came from now. So thanks for the explanations and attention.

Comment: The proof is fine.

Comment: Just as an update to @GerryMyerson's first comment: Shortly (as in: months) after this question was asked, [Yitang Zhang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitang_Zhang) has proved $$\liminf_{n\to \infty} \bigl(p_{n+1} - p_n\bigr) \leqslant 7\cdot 10^7.$$ The bound has been reduced to $246$ unconditionally, and to $12$ or $6$ under the assumption of truth of the [Elliott-Halberstam conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliott%E2%80%93Halberstam_conjecture) and its generalisation respectively.